# A question on variable handling in asynchronous functions. Will this code cause inconsistency?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

Suppose I have two asynchronous functions which may get executed in parallel, and I have a variable declared above the functions, and this variable is accessed and modified by both the functions with each function not being specially aware about the other function. It will cause program inconsistencies..right? for example,

```
var password;

function async generatepassword(){

// it generates the password and stores in the variable password. 

}

function async changepassword(){

// it access and changes the variable password

}
```

The above code might cause inconsistencies on the 'password' variable if  both the functions are called asynchronously and almost in parallel?

Also if I declare a particular variable inside an async function, is it wise not to use the same variable name another async function to declare it again? Or the variables declared inside has a scope only within that asynchronous function?

Comment: Are you sure you understand what differs "async" and "parallel"? Are you sure your functions will be executed "in parallel"? The default Javascript execution model is somewhat specific when it comes to asynchonicity (the event loop), let's first make sure you really mean what you said.

Comment: I meant these two functions could be called at the same time by the triggered events. Each function takes say 5 seconds to complete. Since these both functions are async, it can also start executing before one completes and eventually both the function may work parallel.

Comment: The "async" word doesnt make a function asynchrnous ... the code inside the function make it sync or async, I mean, if you are going to perform a network / dabase / setTimeout operation then, yes, the function is async, if not, the function will be executed sync without unexpected results.
NodeJS will execute the function in the moment you call them, one after another.

Comment: that is a new insight! thanks!  I thought every function specially declared async will be specially considered async function, and it returns a promises, no matter what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this may cause inconsistency if you somehow call this functions one after another **without** await. However you shouldn't.

Just call them like this:

```
await generatepassword();

await changepassword();
```

And you can sleep well.

Comment: Thank you!! One more small question (which I asked in the last paragraph of my question). Will it cause inconsistency if a variable  declared and used in one async function is used in another async function, and both the functions are almost executed in parallel?

Comment: Oh, yes, I forgot about this one. The answer is simple: every function has it's own scope (or more correctly, execution context), so you can declare variables inside a function without a fear to have a conflict with variable from any other function or global scope (execution context). And yes there are only two types of execution contexts: global and function's, if you are interested

Comment: Thank you so much! It helps!!

Comment: You are welcome! Feel free to ask more. Also feel free to mark my answer as correct, so I can get some points :-)

Answer (score 0):

Javascript, by default, runs on a single thread, so, in the moment you call the functions, one function will be executed before the other always, in same order, so, the change in some way is immutable, first apply function 1 and then function 2, without unexpected behaviours depending on the execution.